# Deleting new files after a p4 revert

Tags: perforce

My workflow for testing my changes to our source code on a remote machine is the following:

1) On local machine: Shelve changes that I'd like to test

2) On remote machine (ssh):

```
$ p4 revert //... 
$ p4 sync
$ p4 unshelve -s <changelist number>
$ ./run_test_scripts
```

This seems to work fine when I've only made changes to files that already exists. If I've added new files these will be created during `p4 unshelve`, but not deleted during `p4 revert`. The documentation says that this is what `p4 revert` does so it isn't unexpected, but causes some problems if I want to test the same files again:

```
$ p4 revert //... 
<some file>#none - was add, abandoned
$ p4 sync
File(s) up-to-date.
$ p4 unshelve -s <changelist number>
Can't clobber writable file <some file>
```

Is there way I can delete the files abandoned Perforce?

Comment: Did you try `p4 revert -k //...`?

Comment: @devnull, as far as I can see the `p4 revert -k` also just abandons the files

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is `p4 revert -w`.  From the help:

`The -w flag causes files that are open for add to be deleted from the workspace when they are reverted.`

Note: I'm using the 2013.2/719516 client against a 2013.2/708877 server, in case that switch was added recently...

Comment: In fact, it was added in the 2013.2 release, so you're very up to date!

Comment: That's perfect! Unfortunately we're still on 2013.1 here, so I'll have to wait for the upgrade. Still exactly what I'm looking for

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** just reread your question - this is a **workaround**, perhaps not a full solution...

---

There is a setting in P4Win that allows you to overwrite files when unshelving:

- `Overwrite workspace files even if they are writeable`

I normally use that in combination with another option (again in the gui):

- `Revert checked our files before unshelving`

They solve my problem.

Looking in the console output while running this from the gui, it looks like it is the `-f` parameter in the `unshelve` command.

- `p4 unshelve -s <changelist> -f -c <changelist> <files>`

Comment: Thanks, that certainly works! One thing I'm a bit concerned about with this method is that the files are still there after the revert. This means that the files can *theoretically* be used when compiling and running the tests if I do something stupid. And after all, I'm running tests to avoid doing something stupid... :) I'll leave the question unanswered for a bit more to see if someone has a way to avoid that.

Comment: True. I treat my dev machine as a total hack box - anything goes, so I'm not concerned about what other files might or not be lying around. Builds n Tests get run on separate boxes using clean syncs from P4. (not saying this is best, just saying this is what we do here at the office)

Comment: It may be worth your while just to cut a new branch or stream of the codebase (size permitting) that you can do whatever you want/need with.  Just use it as a playground, then just copy the changes over to the stable stream/branch when they are gtg.

Comment: unfortunately our processes are pretty tightly micromanaged... but yeah that would be a better way to do it