# How to discard all uncommitted changes in Perforce?

Tags: perforce

What is the `p4` command to throw away all my uncommitted change in my Perforce workarea?

When using Git, the analogous command is: `git reset --hard`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you haven't checked out the files you've edited, first do

```
p4 reconcile ...
```

to get the changes tracked by Perforce.

You don't need this if the changes you want to undo are already in any changelist.

Then, from the root of your workspace,

```
p4 revert ...
```

(`...` is the Perforce wildcard for everything under a given directory, not something you have to fill in yourself).

If you also want to delete untracked files from the disk, then if you're using the 2013.2 release or later, you can pass `-w` to `p4 revert` to also delete newly added files. See  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19948915/deleting-new-files-after-a-p4-revert/19964885#19964885) for some background on this option.

The `reconcile` step would first detect these files and mark them for add, and then the `revert` step would unmark them for add and delete them. If `-w` isn't available then there's no clean way to do this and the files will be left untracked and on the disk after the revert.

Comment: Neither of these commands will delete local files that Perforce doesn't know about, which is a critical difference to `git reset --hard`.

Comment: Good point, p4 reconcile will detect them, but p4 revert just reverts the "mark for add" without deleting the files. Seems the new -w flag can handle this, I edited my answer.

Comment: Hmm, I just tried this out. If I cd into a folder under p4 control, and `mkdir testdelete; cd testdelete; touch testdeletefile.txt; cd ..; p4 revert -w .` p4 just says `file(s) not opened on this client`. `git reset --hard` would have deleted the folder. That's a crucial difference for a git user.

Comment: You need to include the 'p4 reconcile ...' step too.

Comment: If I do that I get `testdeletefile.txt opened for add` after the `p4 reconcile ...` step. I want the file to be deleted, which is not what this is doing.

Comment: Yes, but then p4 revert -w will unmark it for add *and delete it from the disk* (I can't test this myself, but according to the linked answer, that's what the -w option adds over and above the normal p4 revert)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66135/discussion-between-damian-and-ganesh-sittampalam).

Comment: Need to take extra cautious with "p4 reconcile ...", it will try search and add anything new.

Answer (score 2):

`p4 revert` is the command you're looking for.

Remember, if you want to revert a specified changelist just, you must specify its changelist number like:

`p4 revert -c changelistnumber`

Or, if you are not running it from the workspace root, specify the workspace/client name, like:

`p4 revert //myWorkspace/...`